# Problem importing CSV/vCARD contacts to S3

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3, import

I have an *S3* I'm attempting to import contacts to.

I started with a list I've converted to `.CSV` and then used an online converter to create `.VCF` files from for each of the contacts.

The *S3* will not import the `.CSV` or `.VCF` files. I've combined the `.VCF` files into 1 and it still refuses to import them.

Is there any other way to do this without creating a *GMail/Google account* to first import them into? (Device is setup with an IMAP account so no need for GMail).

The *S3* reports "`Couldn't import vCard`" then within notification it reads "`The format is not supported`". The `.VCF`'s I have created are *version 2.1*.

What versions of *vCard* does the *S3* support?

Comment: No comments or replies?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without finding a way of doing this I ended up bluetoothing all the contacts from the old handset across (A Samsung B2100).

Would be nice to find more information about this buggy/broken feature on the S3.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I had this issue was a badly formatted vcard file. There were many `BEGIN:VCARD` tags that were not closed with `END:CARD` tags. As an example, it looked like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
BEGIN:VCARD
# Bunch of fields in here like N, FN, EMAIL, etc.
END:VCARD
```

As you can see, the first `BEGIN:VCARD` is not closed.

So in a text editor, I did a Find and Replace to get rid of any unclosed `BEGIN:VCARD`, such that it looked like:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
# Bunch of fields in here like N, FN, EMAIL, etc.
END:VCARD
```

After doing that, the vcf file imported without any problems.

Comment: Hi & thanks for the info dagrha, I don't have this old handset or the .VCF file any longer to check things but your explanation sounds valid and it's totally feasible that was the problem with my data/file.